# SQL Server 2008 - how to zip backup files and move to remote server

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, zip, compression

I have the non-enterprise edition of SQL Server 2008. I do nightly backups, manually zip the files and then manually copy to a remote server.

I need to automate this using batch files. Copying files from server to server is easy but how do I automate the zipping of the backup first?

The full process I need is:

1. Run the backup nightly
2. Zip the backup to reduce size (with a unique zip filename)
3. Move the zip file to a remote server which is setup as a network drive on the database server

I confess the compression part has thrown me off. Any advice would be very much welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can backup databases with [SQLBackupAndFTP](http://sqlbackupandftp.com/) software. It's a simple UI tool with ability to execute and schedule backup jobs (full, diff and log tran backups). It just compresses backups with embedded archiver or 7-zip and send to a local folder or to a NAS drive or FTP or a to a cloud (Dropbox, Google Drive, Amazon S3). Also there is [support forum](http://sqlbackupandftp.com/forum/).

Answer (score 4):

You could (and should!) most definitely investigate the SQL Server [maintenance plans](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187658.aspx).

These allow you to automate things like

- checking for database consistency
- rebuild indexes as needed
- do database and log backups (definitely use the SQL Server 2008 backup compression!!)

I'm not sure if they have built-in support for zipping and copying to a remote server, but you could definitely automate the backup part with a maintenance plan, and the rest with a command file of some sort.

Comment: Thanks marc_s, i have the database backups automated in maintenance plans as you suggested. The problem is that the backups are 2.4GB and take quite a while to copy to a 2nd server. Zipping the backup files reduces the to a mere 300mb. much faster to copy over. I'm stuck on how to automate the zipping of the files

Comment: @Mark: you could set up a batch file to do this, and automate this under Windows "Scheduled Tasks" to run at a given time, e.g. 1 hour after your maintenance plan runs. Just make sure the file is around and abort if it's missing for any reason. Shouldn't be too hard.... most ZIP utilities offer command line interfaces you could use in a batch / Windows .cmd file

Comment: marc_s thanks for the advice, now i have a path to follow. cheers

Answer (score 2):

you do not specify the zip utility that you are using.  There are many, but I tend to use Winzip as that is the main zip tool used at work.  Winzip has a command line interface ( http://www.winzip.com/prodpagecl.htm ) that is a free addin to winzip that can be called from a command line.

Another alternative would be to use cygwin and tar.gz via the command line.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just stuck on how to compress from a batch script:

1. Install 7-Zip
2. Run from the command line:
   "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z MyBackups.7z [Files To Zip]

To get a unique filename, I usually embed the date/time: yyyymmddhhMMss-backup.7z

Answer (score 1):

You can ZIP stuff from the command line, for example with [RAR](http://www.rarlab.com/).  Just add the ZIP commands to wherever you do the copying.  If that's in T-SQL, you can execute a ZIP command using [xp_cmdshell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx).

For a luxury option, check out [Red Gate Backup](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Backup/index.htm), it makes this process fairly painless.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've got 2008, you've got Powershell installed.  I would suggest looking at a psh script executed after a successful backup to compress and copy over the wire.  This would most likely be a second job step after your backup.

You can also go old-school and write a batch file to do the compress and copy.  Then invoke that as a cmdshell job step, again after your backup job/step.

Answer (score 1):

if you are a programmer you can make an application that get your db backup by SMO and zip this file to .gz file by available libraries.

Answer (score 0):

try this link:
[http://www.sqlhub.com/2009/05/copy-files-with-sql-server-from-one.html][1]

in short:

1 - you must enable "Ole Automation Procedures"

2 - modify & run this script to test:

```
DECLARE @FsObjId        INTEGER
DECLARE @Source         VARCHAR(4096)
DECLARE @Destination    VARCHAR(4096)
SET @Source = 'C:\ritesh'
SET @Destination= 'D:\ritesh'
--creare OLE Automation instance
EXEC sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @FsObjId OUTPUT
--call method of OLE Automation
EXEC sp_OAMethod @FsObjId, 'CopyFolder', NULL, @Source, @Destination
--once you finish copy, destroy object
EXEC sp_OADestroy @FsObjId
```

3 - create a maintenance plan:

3.1 - add a "Back Up Database Task" and make sure to choose "Set backup compression" = Compress backup. (this will create your backups in a compressed format)

3.2 - add an "Execute T-SQL Statement Task" with the above script that'll move your files that'll execute after the 3.1 task :).

Answer (score 0):

Try [SQL Backup Master](http://www.sqlbackupmaster.com), which can zip backups and move them to a network (or local) folder. Can also move zipped backup files to FTP, Dropbox, Amazon S3, or Google Drive. Basic edition is free.

Answer (score 0):

Zipping the file after backup takes significant time. Backup programs which use Virtual Device Interface of SQL Server solve your task and decrease overall process time. Try [EMS SQL Backup](http://sqlmanager.net/products/mssql/sqlbackup)  which also allows sending compressed backups to network locations, FTP or clouds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Backup Assistant](https://github.com/sinanbozkus/BackupAssistant). It is going to be a solution.

You need to set a schedule for this program. (like every hour).
And then you need to configure your backup file paths and your ftp credentials in Appsettings.json

```
{   "AppSettings": {
    "BackupPaths": [
      {
        "LocalPath": "C:\\Users\\Sinan\\Desktop\\FtpBackup\\TestDb",
        "RemotePath": "TestDb"
      },
      {
        "LocalPath": "C:\\Users\\Sinan\\Desktop\\FtpBackup\\TestHangFireDb",
        "RemotePath": "TestHangFireDb"
      },
      {
        "LocalPath": "C:\\Users\\Sinan\\Desktop\\FtpBackup\\TestLogDb",
        "RemotePath": "TestLogDb"
      }
    ],
    "BackupFileExtensions": [ ".bak" ],
    "DeleteFilesAfterSend": true,
    "ZipFilesBeforeSend": true,
    "DeleteZipFilesAfterSend": false,
    "WriteLog": true,
    "Providers": {
      "FtpServer": {
        "Enabled": true,
        "Host": "ftphost",
        "Port": "21",
        "Username": "ftpusername",
        "Password": "ftppassword"
      }
    }   } }
```